# HDFS command to find the specific record in a text file based on text / word

Tags: hdfs

I have a text file in HDFS, i need to find a record(s) containing the specific text  word.

**For example:**

```
1,Sam,22,Developer
1,Any,38,Manager
1,Mike,30,TechnicalLead
1,John,32,SM
1,Alice,34,Manager
```

I need to find the records with `Manager` text.

What is the command to get the records based on Manager Text.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below command to find records which contains "Manager".

hadoop fs -cat hdfspath/filename | grep "Manager"